# Parameter expansion with both default and alt_value, that discards parameter value?

Tags: bash

I'm limited to Bash.
I want to echo one of two strings, depending on whever a parameter is set, or not.
Let's say

```
if $ARG is notset|empty then print X
if $ARG is set&nonempty then print V
```

I'm totally not interested in $ARG contents. Just if it is provided&filled or not.

I know I can get this outcome by IF/CASE/etc. But I'll use this construct quite a few times, and I want to keep it concise. I know I can do it in whatever way and wrap it into a function, but I'm curious if it can be made in some smart way i.e. with parameter expansion?

I've read through https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html and a few similar pages, and I noticed that there are two similar, seemingly complementary operations:

```
default value:      ${ARG:-X}
alternative value:  ${ARG:+V}
```

This is where the question title comes from by the way. `:-` returns X when empty, `:+` returns V when nonempty.

A simple:

```
echo ${ARG:+V}${ARG:-X}
```

does *almost* what I want. Prints out `X` when `$ARG` is empty or not set, but in any other case, say ARG=foo, it prints out `Vfoo`. That's because `:+` and `:-` aren't really complementary in the way I want ;) To get it working with simple concatenation like `${}${}` I'd need an 'inverse' `:+` that outputs 'default' when empty, or outputs nothing (not: the tested variable).

Seems I'd need some monster compund command like `${ARG:+V:-X}` (which doesn't work, since it's `:+` with `V:-X` as the alt_value), that does this in a one go, chooses between two given values according to the state of the parameter, and doesn't really use the actual text that parameter holds.

I naively tried nesting

```
echo ${${ARG:+V}:-X}
```

which would do exactly what I needed, and it didn't work in Bash, since it's *parameter* expansion, and the inner `${ARG:+V}` isn't a parameter, so the outer `${}` complains. (~ [Can command substitution be nested in variable substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189426/can-command-substitution-be-nested-in-variable-substitution))

I thought I could try fixing up `Vfoo` by cutting it down to first character `${xxx:0:1}`, but then, this would require nesting again `${${ARG:+V}${ARG:-X}:0:1}`, so no-go.

Or a helper variable, and in this case it's fine:

```
MINGW64 ~
$ f () { T=${1:+V}${1:-X} ; echo ${T:0:1} ; } ;

$ f "a"
V

$ f ""
X

$ f
X
```

This is as close as I could get, and even has the behavior I wanted.
Feels a bit dirty, since it actually constructs arbitrarily-long string `T` just to get its first char. Pure waste.
Also I still would like to squash it into a single expression, without a temporary variable `T`.

Did I miss something in Bash? Can I somehow get this 'choice' behavior in a better way with parameter expansions, or any other built-in tricks?

Comment: Are you looking for `if [[ -z "$ARG" ]]; then echo X; else echo Y; fi`?

Comment: @muru in terms of behavior, yes. But not in terms of writing. I didn't want to use explicit if/then/else or case, since they are so much more to type. I wrote that in 4th para. I focused on parameter expansion specifically because it offers some succint ops like `$(X:-Y)` that are relatively easy to type, less chars, less typos, especially when typed ad-hoc on commandline. And since there already are :- and :+, which are so close, it feels like I overlooked something

Comment: Considering what you have in `f`, this isn't all that worse. It could be shortened to something like `[ -z "ARG" ] && echo X || echo Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
either=(
  'value for unset or empty'
  'value for set and non-empty'
)
printf '%s\n' "${either[!!${#VAR}]}"
```

(disable history expansion (`set +o histexpand`) if trying from an interactive bash invocation).

`${#VAR}` expands to the number of characters in the value of `$VAR`, `!!` is double negation, `!!${#VAR}` as an arithmetic expression yields 0 if the variable is empty or unset and 1 otherwise.

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
print -r -- ${${var:+value for set and non-empty}:-value for unset or empty}
```

Comment: Arrays! Thank you very much. Yep, I already read that with `zsh` I can nest these expressions, but it has to be `bash`. But I forgot that I could just index the array with bool result. It still needs a temp variable for the array, but at least it's now something trivial like `ST=(X V)` . Thanks!